# Formula result is data type (Object), incompatible with expected data type (Text)

Tags: process-builder

I have a simple process builder on opportunity product (on create&edit) to pull value of related Products Family on to a text field (Product_Family_For_Backend_Use) on opportunity product. The process builder was working fine but sometimes its showing error :

> Error element myDecision (FlowDecision).
>   Formula result is data type (Object), incompatible with expected data type (Text).
>   Flow Details
>   Flow Name: Update_Product_Family_For_Backend_Use_on_opportunity_product
>   Type: Record Change Process
>   Version: 1
>   Status: Active
>   Org: Kaptivo Inc (00D1I000002L326)
>   Flow Interview Details
>   Interview Label: Update_Product_Family_For_Backend_Use_on_opportunity_product-1_InterviewLabel
>   Current User: Celeste Henkelmann (0051I000000nyMB)
>   Start time: 8/28/2018 7:57 AM
>   Duration: 0 seconds
>   How the Interview Started
>   Celeste Henkelmann (0051I000000nyMB) started the flow interview.
>   Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
>   myVariable_old = null
>   myVariable_current = 00k1I00000VdcjbQAB
>   ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
>   {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}
>   Result
>   {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "8/28/2018 7:57 AM"
>   Salesforce Error ID: 1730798143-47888 (56480063)

Decision Element:-

[image]

Update Action:-

[image]

Any suggestions how this could be happening some times and not others? Also what could be the problem.

other than one custom text field.... all other fields & object used in this process are standard..

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you update the question with criteria and action of your process builder? So that we can have the better picture to analyse your problem.I guess the problem is with them.

Comment: Hi Sanket, I have updated question with screenshots.

Comment: Why don't you use a formula field. Anything on the product object is available on the opportunity line item using a formula without the need for a worklow?

Comment: because i want the resulted field to use in rollup summary. And if i do the formula then i can't do rolloup.

Comment: @dnynahswar ...In that case, contrary to the other user, I have always used the check for id first clause because PB will do before insert which means that there is no record id yet. Salesforce may say differently, but I have seen errors.    Also, I don't see anything wrong with this at all. The datatype is saying that it is attempting to put the Product2 object, which makes no sense. Also this intermittent. You probably need to create a case with saleforce.

Comment: Also, may want to try using a workflow rule. I found they are less prone to strange errors compared to PB. Your logic is pretty straightforward and should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I have raised case with salesforce....hope they find anything.

Comment: I got reply from salesforce saying : "it seems that this is caused by the API version that is being used on record creation "

Comment: Hi...the error seems to disappear when i replaced process builder with workflow. Thanks @disasterlooms your solution was the one that actually worked. Thanks everyone else for providing other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the problem is occurring, but following approach might solve your issue permanently.

First, no need to put a condition like `Opportunity.Product2.Id is not null`, because, Opportunity line item doesn't exist without a product. So, it should be `No criteria—just execute the actions!`

Secondly, for update action, use formula of return type `Text` and refer the product family.

[image: update action]

Comment: Tried...same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with updating the field. You are supposed to wrap your Product Family field in **TEXT** function. Product Family field is being treated as the Object and your formula is expecting a text.

So change update type to *Formula* and in the formula builder use the following -

> Text([OpportunityLineItem].Product2.Family)

I hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes...i tried it but same error.

Comment: Do you have any other workflow/formula/process builder on this object? I will check them since everything seems to be okay with this PB.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when changing the API name of one of the fields used in the flow.
The solution is to clone the process and save it making sure it had the new API name in it.